# NSLog disable from certain classes and DEBUG

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

Hello guys I have found this code that is used to create a different NSLog (without data and timestamps) that displays the class where the log was made and the line number.
I have read that is possible to disable the logging only for certain classes with NO_LOG but there was not explained how to use it exactly, I am quite new to obj-c and I appreciate an explanation on how to disable logging for certain classes and how to activate and deactivate the debugging. thanks

```
#define MAKESTRING(__VA_ARGS__) #__VA_ARGS__
#define TOSTRING(...) MAKESTRING(__VA_ARGS__)

static inline void PxReportv(BOOL doLog, char const *file, int line, NSString *prefix,     NSString *fmt, va_list argList) {
if (doLog) {
    NSString *fileNameWithExtension = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", file]     lastPathComponent]; 
#ifdef NO_LOG
    NSString *fileName = [fileNameWithExtension stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    char *f = TOSTRING(NO_LOG);
    NSArray *comps = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", f] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for (NSString *except in comps) {
        if ([except isEqualToString:fileName]) {
            return;
        }
    }
#endif
    vprintf([[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ <%@ [%d]> %@\n", prefix, fileNameWithExtension, line, fmt] arguments:argList] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL);
}
}

static inline void PxReport(BOOL doLog, char const *file, int line, NSString *prefix, NSString *fmt, ...) {
va_list ap;
va_start(ap, fmt);
PxReportv(doLog, file, line, prefix, fmt, ap);
va_end(ap);
}

#define PxError(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"[ERROR]", __VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef DEBUG
#define PxDebug(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"[DEBUG]", __VA_ARGS__)
#define NSLog(...) PxReport(YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, @"", __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define PxDebug(...)
#define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

Comment: I re-wrote my logging some time ago: [link](https://github.com/pixelflut/PixLib-OpenSource/blob/master/PixLib%20OpenSource/PxLogger.m) as i prefere a more object-oriented way. This makes it easier to disable loging in specific files using `[PxLogger setSilenceFiles:@["yourFileName"]]`

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
#define NO_LOG 1
```

**before** `#import`ing the file you've shown above.

BTW a better implementation would define `PxDebug()` and `NSLog()` to nothing if `NO_LOG` was defined...

Comment: `NO_LOG` is meant to be a file-list, so using it would be `#define NO_LOG file1,file2`

Comment: @JonathanCichon Thanks - I think you are right. What a crap piece of code.

Comment: thanks ;), but it is old and so it worked taking arguments from the comandline.

Comment: @JonathanCichon Did you write it then?  I had no idea.  I think the idea of using an `inline` is bad (there are as many copies of that function as there are implementation files) and it should be logging to a file with date/time, logging levels, thread ids and class and method names.

Answer (score 1):

that is quite a verbose solution, i made one that is a lot neater than that

```
#ifndef DebugLog_h
#define DebugLog_h

#if DEBUG

#define DLog(...)   do{\
    printf("[%s:%d]", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);\
    NSString *_S_ =  [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__];\
    printf(" %s\n",[_S_ cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);\
    }while(0);

#else

    #define DLog(...)

#endif

#endif
```

that will print the line number, class and function it came from

eg:

Dlog(@"hello %d", 123);

[-[SomeViewController viewWillAppear:]:91] hello 123

edit: if you add the file to your `projectname-Prefix.pch` file, then you can use it without having to include it everywhere

and it will automatically be taken out of release builds, because DEBUG is defined as a project definition automatically when its in debug mode

Comment: Isn't logging the class and method name more useful than logging the file and line number?

Comment: well normally your files are named the same as your classes and if you have the line number, you can tell what method its in

Comment: I rather want the file, line no btw :D It is much more concrete and you can exactly see at what instruction it crashed

Comment: ah lol, well just add `#define _FILE_ (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)` and `printf("[%s:%d]", _FILE_, __LINE__);` back (or just look at the edit revision history)